# MYSQL Query ignoring results in php

Tags: php, mysql

editing this question as it has been narrowed down more. If i manually run a SQL query as per below, it shows no results even though i know that nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '2' has at least 5 results that should show.

```
SELECT
CONCAT(title,' ',first_name,' ',last_name) AS lead_name,
nfw_leads.mobile,
nfw_leads.lead_date,
nfw_leads.service_type,
nfw_leads.state,
nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply
FROM
nfw_users
LEFT JOIN nfw_leads ON nfw_leads.allocate_to = nfw_users.id_num
LEFT JOIN nfw_lead_messages_sent ON nfw_lead_messages_sent.sent_to_id = nfw_leads.allocate_to
WHERE
nfw_users.id_num = '3513'
GROUP BY
    nfw_leads.first_name,
    nfw_leads.last_name,
    nfw_leads.mobile,
    nfw_leads.service_type

HAVING nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '2'
Order by
    lead_date ASC
```

If i manually run with SQL query nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '1' the results show. See below for one that works with = '1' but doesnt work when i change it to = '2'

```
SELECT
CONCAT(title,' ',first_name,' ',last_name) AS lead_name,
nfw_leads.mobile,
nfw_leads.lead_date,
nfw_leads.service_type,
nfw_leads.state,
nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply
FROM
nfw_users
LEFT JOIN nfw_leads ON nfw_leads.allocate_to = nfw_users.id_num
LEFT JOIN nfw_lead_messages_sent ON nfw_lead_messages_sent.sent_to_id = nfw_leads.allocate_to
WHERE
nfw_users.id_num = '3513'
GROUP BY
    nfw_leads.first_name,
    nfw_leads.last_name,
    nfw_leads.mobile,
    nfw_leads.service_type

HAVING nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '1'
Order by
    lead_date ASC
```

Comment: Try to echo $x before executing and post code

Comment: because where it echos: $ACC_SQL towards the bottom its after a GROUP BY which means it should be HAVING *i think*

Answer (score 0):

first thing cast $data to integer

```
   $data = intval($_GET["data"]));
```

then use it as follows

```
   if($data === 1) {
   } elseif($data === 2) {
   } elseif(empty($data)) {
   }
```

Comment: ok i have made the changes as you suggest and made each section different mysql slightly. Its showing 32 records no matter what i choose. But i know im hitting the right section when i click each button because it echos out as it should. You can see changes here: http://pastebin.com/V4ps42Sr

And yes i already tried to change to  $data = intval($_GET["data"]); doesnt make a difference  :(

Comment: ok move the nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '1' part from where to join condition and check it.

Comment: Ok so manually running a sql putting nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '1' shows results. but putting nfw_lead_messages_sent.reply = '2' shows no results. There should be at least 5 results for '2' Ill paste the sql query below

Comment: i re-wrote the original question above so it makes more sense

Comment: ok can you print the query before executing it, and send me the result for it? for both inputs

Comment: Ok so here is the echoed query before execution for the one that doesnt show any results even though there should be: http://pastebin.com/muL8d3FT

and this one is for the one that shows results but shows all results including the ones that should have shown in the other query..

http://pastebin.com/uFvWYHzM